# Run CLR app without the .NET Framework installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, clr, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I was wondering if it’s possible to run a CLR (C++/CLI) app **without** the .NET Framework installed on the target machine.

Since CLR apps depend upon the .NET Framework DLL’s *(I think)* is there a way to copy the used DLLs to the output folder instead of installing the .NET Framework?

I’m building my CLR app in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 with .NET Framework 1.0 - 4.5.2 installed and VC++ 2017 *(The latest one, I forgot lol)*

Comment: Since .NET 4.5.2, the framework has been considered by MS to be part of the OS. As such, you need to make sure that the OS has been appropriately updated to a matching version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Not without the app being dotnetcore and bringing the runtime in it's own installer into it's own FOLDER - supported for core (which in 3.0 can handle UI in 2019), NOT supported before that, you must install .NET framework.

Though, .NET framework is part of many thigns these days - Powershell demands it - so any modern windows should have a version installed. Not the MOST current though.